# From PHP array to jQuery array sent via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Now this is a pretty simple question, but due to my lack of jQuery knowledge I have to ask this..

In JS I have this variable, which is an array of marker data for Google Maps:

```
var Locations = {
        1: {
            info: '1. New Random info and new position',
            lat: -37,
            lng: 124.9634
        },
        2: {
            info: '2. New Random info and new position',
            lat: 70,
            lng: 14.5144
        },
        3: {
            info: '3. New Random info', 
            lat: 30,
            lng: 24.5144
        },
        4: {
            info: '4. New Random info', 
            lat: 34,
            lng: 26.5144
        },
        5: {
            info: '5. 55555. Added',
            lat: -37,
            lng: 0
        }
    };
```

I then have an ajax call to retrieve a new array of locations with PHP.
The PHP looks like this example (note that I echo 3 pieces of data delimited by | ):

```
$arrayccordinates = array(); 
$countercords = 0;
echo 'Data1 |';
echo 'Data2 |';
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $countercords = $countercords + 1;
    $arrayccordinates[] = array( $countercords => array( 'info' => $infos, 'lat' => $latdata, 'lng' => $lngdata ) 
    );
}
echo json_encode($arrayccordinates);
```

Here is the ajax call. Here I split the 3 data pieces up and the locations array is found in arr[2].:

```
//Ajax code
var interval = 5000;  // 5000 ms = 5 secs
function doAjax() {
    jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/codes/LiveVisitsStats/postlivecounter.php',
            dataType : 'html',
            success: function (data) {
            var arr = data.split('|');
                    jQuery('#counterint').html(arr[0]);
                    jQuery('#extrainfoscounter').html(arr[1]);   
                    jQuery('#testdiv').html(arr[2]);  

            var newlocations = arr[2];        
                },
            complete: function (data) {
                    // Schedule the next
                    setTimeout(doAjax, interval);
            }
    });
}
```

Now, I have tested this and it doesn´t seem to work. The array from PHP stored in "newlocations" variable does not seem to work as the original "Locations" variable.
I have really no clue what I´m doing wrong, though I suspect my use of json_encode is completely wack..

Comment: Are you using jQuerys' data option for your ajax requests? scratch that. i understand.

Comment: I´m more or less using the ajax script I have posted. I have set datatype to HTML, which probably is wrong in this case. The problem is that I really have no clue when it comes to this kind of ajax handling and JS arrays..

Comment: have you tried changing your dataType to json? When you send json_encode data from a php script to the success function of ajax, you can then use the associative array like `data.key1` or the index like `data[0].innerKey`

Comment: dataType: 'json', as you are getting json back

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the datatype to html, but sending JSON. If you set `datatype: json`, then jquery will decode the json into a native JS array for you.

And besides, since you ARE outputting JSON from PHP, there almost certainly won't be ANY `|` characters in the string to split on.

Answer (score 1):

As i mentioned in my comments: if you change dataType from html to json you can use the argument inside the success function like you would an array object in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Your "array" looks like this:

```
var Locations = {
        1: {
            info: '1. New Random info and new position',
            lat: -37,
            lng: 124.9634
        },
        2: {
            info: '2. New Random info and new position',
            lat: 70,
            lng: 14.5144
        },
        3: {
            info: '3. New Random info', 
            lat: 30,
        ...
```

which is not an array, but an object with properties 1, 2, 3 etc. pointing to an object

Your php `json_encode` will return:

```
[
   { "1": {
        info: '1. New Random info and new position',
        lat: -37,
        lng: 124.9634
    }},
    { "2": {
        info: '1. New Random info and new position',
        lat: -37,
        lng: 124.9634
    }},
    ...
```

which is a valid array of objects having a property "1", "2", etc pointing to a nested object - quite a difference.

Either change the layout of your initial object (and the code accessing) or don't use  `json_encode`

Comment: Thanks, that pretty much hits the nail on its head, I think.
Then my question is.. What is the easiest way to "convert" my json array to an object, identical to the "Locations" variable? (of course with new updated data)

Comment: Maybe I could do something like this in ajax success data function??:
var myNewObj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

Comment: Chang this line `$arrayccordinates[] = array( $countercords => array( 'info' => $infos, 'lat' => $latdata, 'lng' => $lngdata )` to `$arrayccordinates[$countercords] = array( 'info' => $infos, 'lat' => $latdata, 'lng' => $lngdata );` and use `json_encode(...., JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)` in oder to force an object and you're pretty much done.

Comment: I could almost kiss you right now! Absolutely brilliant!
That did the trick and now it´s working as needed, thank you so much, good sir!

Comment: hehem ok then. I will try to restrain myself

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Axel Amthor I figured it all out.
I just needed to change 2 minor things.

Firstly I needed to change the PHP code to this:

```
$arrayccordinates = array(); 
$countercords = 0;
foreach ($results as $result) {
$countercords = $countercords + 1;
$arrayccordinates[$countercords] = array( 'info' => $result->info, 'lat' => $result->lat, 'lng' => $result->lng);
}
echo json_encode($arrayccordinates);
```

Then I needed to modify my Ajax call slightly into this:

```
//Ajax code
var interval = 5000;  // 1000 = 1 second, 3000 = 3 seconds
function doAjax() {
    jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/codes/LiveVisitsStats/postlivecounter.php',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {

            var NewLocation = data;                                                   

            },
            complete: function (data) {
                    // Schedule the next
                    setTimeout(doAjax, interval);
            }
    });
}
setTimeout(doAjax, interval);
```

Of course I then need to make seperate ajax calls for other kind of ajax updates..